# Best way to graph probabilities of feature vectors

Tags: probability, data-visualization, graphical-model

I have a lot of feature vectors in the form of:
v1=[x0, x1, x2, x3, x4]
where x0, x1, and x2 can take binary values. either 0 or 1
x3 and x4 can take values from 0 up to 9

I have a lot of vectors that covers more than the entire space. Each vector corresponds to a class so for example

v1 = [0 , 1 , 1 , 5 , 9] corresponds to class A

the same feature vector can correspond to different classes so another instance of v1 in the example above can correspond to class B. I want to have a graph or graphs that represents the probabilities a certain feature vector will belong to a certain class. What is the best way to do this? I thought about converting the feature vector into a number and then plotting this number in the x axis but it will be hard to get information from this graph.

Comment: how about drawing something like a decision tree with class probabilities at the leafs?

Comment: this is a cool idea but there will be 800 leaves in this case! too much to fit in a paper :)

Comment: I see. :) How about making a tree out of first 3 variables (8 branches, total, right?) Then for each leaf you can have a 10x10 table for the rest two variables. And class probabilities would be either entered into the 10x10 table or maybe coded with color?

Comment: that sounds like a cool idea